# C#, variables outside foreach loop and thread.sleep

Tags: c#

I can not use the variable that I declared inside the foreach loop which are 'minute' and 'hour' from outside, so that makes me use that linq and foreach stuff in all three methods over and over again.

And I can not keep using my program like I can not click other buttons and stuff because of this Thread.Sleep, what can I use instead?

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("date.xml");
DateTime thisDate = DateTime.Now;

int now;
int operationTime;
int neatTime;

var date = from i in xdoc.Descendants("date")
    select new
        {
            Hour = i.Element("hour").Value,
            Minute = i.Element("minute").Value,
        };

foreach (var item in date)
    {
        int hour = Convert.ToInt32(item.Hour);
        int minute = Convert.ToInt32(item.Minute);
        now = (thisDate.Hour * 3600) + (thisDate.Minute * 60);
        operationTime = (hour * 3600) + (minute * 60);
        if (operationTime < now)
        {
            neatTime = (24 * 3600) - (now - operationTime);
        }
        else
        {
            neatTime = operationTime - now;
        }
        while (neatTime > 0)
        {
            neatTime--;
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
        Process.Start("shutdown", "/s /t 0");
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean with `I can not use the variable that I declared inside the foreach loop which are 'minute' and 'hour' from outside`. Where do you want to use them?

Comment: why are you calling the shutdown command inside a loop...thus calling it multiple times

Comment: If you're trying to get the total seconds, you could avoid doing the math operations and do something like: `now = (int)thisDate.TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds;` and `operationTime = (int)item.TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds;`

Comment: Instead of a `while` loop that just sleeps for a second and decrements a variable, you may as well just remove the loop and do: `Thread.Sleep(neatTime * 1000);` And your outside `foreach` loop is not necessary anyway, since after the first iteration you reboot the machine. What are you *actually* trying to do? What is the big picture here?

Comment: Alright, thank you, I've done it, how to close this question? Big picture was making a timer for pc to shutdown-restart or alert when the time comes, I actually asked the same question here but someone told me to narrow my question, but it made it fail to understand, check this out, sorry for this brain-burner question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49890431/c-using-variables-outside-a-loop-and-some-problems-about-my-project

Comment: Click the 'delete' link underneath it. Unless one of the answers solved your problem, then mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re: unable to use variables inside the foreach loop - 
What you're looking for is a global variable, in order to use it throughout the rest of the script. You can declare the variables outside the loop and assign the values inside it:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("date.xml");
DateTime thisDate = DateTime.Now;

int now;
int operationTime;
int neatTime;
int hour;
int minute;

var date = from i in xdoc.Descendants("date")
    select new
        {
            Hour = i.Element("hour").Value,
            Minute = i.Element("minute").Value,
        };

foreach (var item in date)
    {
        hour = Convert.ToInt32(item.Hour);
        minute = Convert.ToInt32(item.Minute);

        //Rest of code here
    }
```

Re: Not using Thread.Sleep() - You can use an IENumerator method instead. This method will run at the same time as your original thread continues on e.g.

```
public IEnumerator PauseWhileStillRunning()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
    Process.Start("shutdown", "/s /t 0");
}
```

You can then call this method by calling `StartCoroutine(PauseWhileStillRunning())`

Answer (score 1):

You can use variables out of loops if you declare them outside the loop.
For example :

```
int count = 0;
for(int i =1; i<=10; i++)
    count++;
console.writeLine(count) // print 10
```